# Print time at which minimum distance occurs given a set of reference distance values

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

From a list of values in list A, I want to know the time (first column) for a list B in which the minimum distances with values of the list A occur (distances reported in second column).

```
import numpy

list_A = np.loadtxt('listA.dat')
file_B = np.loadtxt('listB.dat')

distances = file_B[:,1]
time = file_B[:,0]

abs_differences = []

for point in list_A:
    diffs = []
    for distance in distances:
        diffs.append(abs(distance-point))
        list={}
        list=['Point'] = point
        list=['AbsDiff'] = diffs
        abs_differences.append(list)

for ele in abs_differences:
   diffs = ele['AbsDiff']
   index = diffs.index(min(diffs))
   with open("output.txt","a") as f:
       print(time[index], file=f)
```

However, the output file takes a really long time to be written, since the time at which the minimum distance occurs for every point of list B is printed for every point of the dataset, therefore having multiple occurrences of the time values. Is there a way to solve this issue, possibly simplifying the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are switching between types several times and using the python keyword *list* as a variable name, so your code cannot work properly at least for these two reasons.

You should try something based on the following simplified code:

```py
import numpy as np

list_A = np.loadtxt('listA.dat')
file_B = np.loadtxt('listB.dat')

list_B = file_B[:,1]
times = file_B[:,0]

min_times = []  # list of tuples (pointA, pointB, indexB, distance, time)
for pointA in list_A:
    min_distance = float('inf')
    min_time = None
    
    for indexB, pointB in enumerate(list_B):
        distance = abs(pointA - pointB)
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
            min_time = times[indexB]
    min_times.append((pointA, pointB, indexB, min_distance, min_time))
    

print(min_times)

# if you want the distances: (index 3 in the tuple)
print([mt[3] for mt in min_times])

# you can also write to file once you are sure of the result wanted
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help! How do I print in a column just the min_time field?
If I print min_times, I just print all the fields of the tuple in brackets.

Comment: You're welcome. I did not try as I don't have the exact same data as you but the last line should do it: print([mt[3] for mt in min_times]). It generates a comprehension list with only the 3rd index of each element, and then prints it.

Comment: I tried with the following
`with open("output.txt") as f:
    print([mt(4) for mt in min_times], file=f)`
without succeding in call the tuple object.

Comment: Before writing to a file, you need to convert it to string:

with open("output.txt") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([str(mt[4]) for mt in min_times])